# How can I calculate the frequency using different color bands?

Tags: frequency

Let's say that I have a 1 dimensional signal that has data which comes from one of 2 different spectral bands. The measurements come evenly mixed between the two bands. I'm interested in a method of extending the frequency calculation by combining information from both signals.

To show an example, let's just say that I have a Red band and a Green Band. The detector arrays would look like this: `RGRGRGRGRG`. Let's say that I had 512 R, and 512 G, just to give a concrete example. As the detectors are neighboring each other, and most signals have some component of red and green, it seems likely that a common frequency calculation could be made by combining the bands, and possibly double the frequency range which can be detected. How could I best go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean spatial frequency (e.g. from a 1D slice of a still photo), temporal frequency (e.g. from a single pixel of a video), or some combination of the two (e.g. from a 1D slice of a video)?

Comment: @Data: All 3 would be interesting, but for the purpose of this question, let's say spatial.

Comment: Is the idea to, say, increase the resolution of the image by combining information from the red and green channels [by exploiting knowledge about the physical sensor layout/characteristics]?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm hoping to see higher frequencies than could otherwise be detected. It seems like it must be possible to get info, essentially combining the bands to get a sensor with twice the resolution, thus being able to detect twice the frequency, but I'm at a bit of a loss at the exact method of doing so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a practical perspective, there's good news and there's bad news.  The good news is that, in a sense, consumer grade digital cameras [at least] already do something like what you're describing, so there's a large amount of information available about the process, which is called [demosaicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing).  The bad news is that, in "standard" designs, the various RAW color channels actually have *lower* resolution than the physical sensor array, and the color channels in non-RAW images have already been reconstructed.

The reason for this is that the physical sensors only detect light intensity (not color), and therefore each available physical "pixel" is paired with a color filter, according to some pattern. For example, the [Bayer Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) is a common pattern which allocates 50% of the available spatial resolution to the green channel, but only 25% each to the red and blue channels.  The various spatial patterns are called [Color Filter Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array) (CFAs).  In effect they model the *idea* of separate RGB sensors, just in a more cost-effective manner.  If there is some way of exploiting "spectral crosstalk" from the materials used in a given CFA, it would be handled in the context of demosaicing.

That means, if you're dealing with a camera which uses that type of sensing scheme, the most reasonable thing you can hope for is access to the camera RAW data (i.e. un-demosaiced), from which you can apply a higher-quality demosaicing algorithm to reconstruct the image.  From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing):

> When one has access to the raw image data from a digital camera, one
>   can use computer software with a variety of different demosaicing
>   algorithms instead of being limited to the one built into the
>   camera...The differences in rendering the finest detail (and grain
>   texture) that come from the choice of demosaicing algorithm are among
>   the main differences between various raw developers; often
>   photographers will prefer a particular program for aesthetic reasons
>   related to this effect.

The following link seems to be a good overview of various reconstruction algorithms:

[A Study of Spatial Color Interpolation Algorithms for Single-Detector Digital Cameras](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/1999/psych221/projects/99/tingchen/)

In higher-end cameras, however, the RAW color channels might not even be spatially interleaved.  Two of the different higher-end schemes (beam splitting, temporal interleaving) are reviewed [here](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cameras-photography/digital/digital-camera4.htm).

One type of sensor that I think works more like what you had in mind is the [Foveon X3 Sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foveon_X3_sensor). The following paragraph from the link gives a good overview of the resolution issues:

> For example, the dimensions of the photosite array in the sensor in
>   the Sigma SD10 camera are 2268 × 1512, and the camera produces a
>   native file size of those dimensions (times three color layers). This
>   amounts to approximately 3.4 million three-color pixels. However, it
>   has been advertised as a 10.2 MP camera by taking account of the fact
>   that each photosite contains stacked red, green, and blue color
>   sensing photodiodes, or pixel sensors (2268 × 1512 × 3). By
>   comparison, the dimensions of the photosite array in the 10.2 MP Bayer
>   sensor in the Nikon D200 camera are 3872 × 2592, but there is only one
>   photodiode, or one pixel sensor, at each site. The cameras have equal
>   numbers of photodiodes, and produce similar RAW data file sizes, but
>   the Bayer filter camera produces a larger native file size via
>   demosaicing.

I think this is what you're looking for, assuming I understood the question.